# Creating an animation with SX property - MUI v5

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui

I'm trying to create an animation of a spinning svg as a loader,
checking online I've seen some examples of doing it with Styled component, which is deprecated.

Been wondering if you guys have a suggestion?
I tried adding an '@keyframes spin' property to my SX but it didn't do anything, I.E:

```
<Box
 sx={{ 
 animation: '$test 1s linear infinite',
 '@keyframes spin': {
   from: {
    transform: 'rotate(0dg)'
  },
   to: {
    transform: 'rotate(360dg)'
  }
 }
}}
>
```

I tried creating an animation with SX property of MUI v5 with the same logic as Styled component
but failed :(

I wonder if we can achieve it without using a CSS file & a class...

Answer (score 7):

With MUI5 it's works just fine when add keyframes on SX props
Here is my example

```
            <Box sx={{
                "@keyframes width-increase": {
                    "0%": {
                        width: "100px"
                    },
                    "100%": {
                        width: "300px"
                    }
                },
                width: "100px",
                height: "50px",
                backgroundColor: "red",
                animation: "width-increase 1s ease infinite",
            }}></Box>
```

Make sure you init keyframes before use.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: thanks for the answer bud, my problem was I wrote 'dg' instead of 'deg'

Answer (score 2):

You gave your @keyframe the name "spin" - but didn't call it when you gave properties to your animation. Simply replacing $test with spin should do it.

```
<Box
 sx={{ 
 animation: 'spin 1s linear infinite',
 '@keyframes spin': {
   from: {
    transform: 'rotate(0dg)'
  },
   to: {
    transform: 'rotate(360dg)'
  }
 }
}}
>
```